# Are the Model-driven architecture feasible?

Tags: platform-independent, mda, model-driven-development

I want to ask some questions about MDA:

First, I know that there exist tools that you can write code in one language and then the code be generated in another, for example in 'GWT' Java code is transformed to Javascript, or some mobile development tools that transform HTML+Javascript to native code for different platforms. Are these transformations consider as MDA or is something different?

Except that using MDA part of the code is generated automatically are there any other reason that increase programmer's productivity?

Compared to traditional development, will switching to MDA worth the value (immediately) and is that possible in reality?

Answer (score 0):

your knowledge about MDA is less or defective.
main goal of MDA is modeling and in all levels (cim-oim-psm) we are working with model and write 0 line of code, yes input and output of MDA levels is model.
another important activity in MDA is transformation that there are many transformation tools.
i think you should studding first about MDA and transformation (also stereotype).

Answer (score 0):

> ...
>   Are these transformations consider as MDA or is something different?

In general, no. But you can use MDA approach for making such transformations.

> Except that using MDA part of the code is generated automatically are there >any other reason that increase programmer's productivity?

Yes, it gives you clear picture of system which is free from platform specific details.

> Compared to traditional development, will switching to MDA worth the value > (immediately) and is that possible in reality?

Yes, it worth the value, not immediately, but in long run. Yes, switching to MDA is possible in reality.